# USB Autorun automatically saving html file

Tags: passwords, save, usb, auto, autorun

I working on a password recovery system using WebBrowserPassViewer on a USB. It uses Autorun.inf to open the password collection app which is then saved to usbdriver.bat. The problem is I want it to automatically save the html file (under "View," labeled "HTML Report - All Items") to the USB drive. I can't figure out how to do this.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq1AZ.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVppd.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/S86gD.png)